# How can i create both the child and parent object in one request Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nested-object

I have a company object that has a **OneToOneField(Profile)**, and Profile has **OneToOneField(User)**
My question is: is it possible to create all three in one request and if so, how can i do it?

**Structure of my company object**

```
"company":{

    "profile" :{

        "user" : {

            "first_name" : "",
            "last_name" : "",
            "username" : "",
            "email" : ""
        },

        "phone" : "",

        "registered_date" : ""

    },

    "name": "",
    "address": "",
    "currency": "",
    "id_number": "",
    "vat_number": "",
    "vat_company_name": "",
    "company_email": "",
    "fixed_phone": ""
}
```

I tried sending this into the POST request to the Company serializer and this is what i get:

```
{
    "profile": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."
    ]
}
```

Can i do this without overriding `.create()` in the serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it from a single API. You can update your serializers `create` method. As you are explaining the input request format you can do the following changes in your serilizer.

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
  profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
  user_data = profile_data.pop('user')
  user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
  profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
  company = Company.objects.create(profile=profile, **validated_data)
  return company
```

The above example is the solution to your question. You can add extra information and play with the data as your requirement inside the create function.

Comment: Im still getting the same error 
"Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."